# errorChannel not recognised After Throwing Exception form ChannelInterceptor

Tags: spring-integration

I tried to Throw some Exception from ChennelInterceptor.But it's not sending the message to ErrrorChannel i have defined.

Below the snippet.

```
 <int-file:inbound-channel-adapter id="fileInBound" 
            channel="fileProcessingChannel"
            directory="${file.processing.folder}" 
            prevent-duplicates="true"
            filename-pattern="*.txt">
</int-file:inbound-channel-adapter>
<int:channel id="fileProcessingChannel">
    <int:queue/>
</int:channel>
<!--Setting the Error Channel -->
 <int:header-enricher input-channel="inputchannel" output-channel="testChannel">
    <int:error-channel ref="myErrorChannel" overwrite="true"></int:error-channel>
</int:header-enricher>

<!-- Accepts only the File data Type -->
<int:channel id="testChannel" >
    <int:interceptors>
        <bean class="com.abc.SomeValidationInterceptor"></bean>
    </int:interceptors> 
</int:channel>

<int:channel id="myErrorChannel">
</int:channel>

<int:service-activator input-channel="myErrorChannel" output-channel="nullChannel">
        <bean class="com.abc.MyErrorHandlerEndpoint"></bean>    
</int:service-activator>
```

Am throwing exception i.e MessagingException from com.abc.SomeValidationInterceptor.And i expect to reach myErrorChannel but it snot reaching myErrorChannel.

Any idea why its not working.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work that way. You generally should not manipulate the `errorChannel` header yourself, except in very specialized circumstances.

How are you getting messages into `inputChannel`.

In general, you should use a gateway of some kind and declare an `error-channel` on that; letting the framework handle the headers; the exception is caught by the gateway and the `ErrorMessage` routed appropriately.

Similarly, an `error-channel` can be defined on the poller for polled endpoints.

Comment: See more info from Reference Manual: http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/latest-ga/reference/html/configuration.html#namespace-errorhandler

Comment: Thanks Gary.Actually i am processing the file form file:inbound-channel-adater.I have updated the config information in my original POST.